# WPF Mouse busy icon

Tags: wpf, mouse, icons

What's the best method in WPF for showing an Eggtimer/Busy mouse icon when opening a new window or retrieving records from a DB?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way is to set [Mouse.OverrideCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor.aspx):

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
try
{
    // perform task
}
finally
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
}
```

Comment: You can also wrap this in a disposable class if you prefer using the using statement.

public class OverrideCursorDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public OverrideCursorDisposable(Cursor cursor)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = cursor;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        }
    }